# Renderscript compilation errors - where are they?

Tags: android-renderscript, android-studio-3.3

When I have an error in RenderScript, I basically get an exception from the compiler.  I don't want to paste the entir eexception here since it's pretty meaningless, but the gist of it is:

```
Error while executing process
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'llvm-rs-cc.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:395)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
```

Why am I not getting any meaningful compiler warnings and errors about the script itself?  The above was caused by me introducing an intentional syntax error.

I'm using

```
renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

and a fresh install of android studio 3.3